# Merge multiple columns from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to merge multiple columns from different tables. My code is taking forever to query. Is this the correct way of merging multiple tables? Is there a more efficient way of doing this. I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.5.

```
SELECT 
  i.id, i.hdm_id, i.tos,
  c.itemid, c.cid, 
  pr.code,
  p.lag

  FROM Table1 i
  JOIN Table2 c ON
  i.id = c.id 

  JOIN Table3 pr ON
  c.id = pr.id

 JOIN Table4 p ON
 pr.id = p.id ;
```

Comment: Lookup indexes.

Comment: Indexes won't help for joining whole tables

Comment: @JustMe is right, besides if the `id` fields are primary keys they will anyway be indexed.

Comment: Show as explain analyze for this query and tables ddl

Comment: Indexes will indeed help doing joins, no matter if it's whole tables or not.

Comment: Maybe, it depends on the statistics and how much data needs to be taken from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to create indexes covering your query

```
create index ix_table1 on table1(id, hdm_id, tos)
create index ix_table2 on table2(id, itemid)
create index ix_table3 on table3(id, code)
create index ix_table4 on table4(id, lag)
```

You should think seriously about the necessity of such query. Do you really need *all* the data?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't the JOINS. It isn't missing indices either (although they might help, so look into those). Your problem is that you're indiscriminately joining 4 tables and selecting them all. Depending on how many rows are in each, that'll take a while to execute.

I would suggest you narrow down what you actually need from these tables (like reining in what data you need with a WHERE statement where appropriate).

You could also create a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html) in Postgresql. This functions like a normal view, but the results of the query are stored in between runs so multiple runs of it will be faster if the data doesn't change meanwhile. The downside of these is you can't directly update/delete/insert into them, so you'll have to mind that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following things:

1) Check for Index fragmentation and follow the steps as mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes

2) While using JOINS, you should consider order of the tables as well. Whichever table has less number of records, use that first . So next subsequent joins will have less number of records to filter.

3) Use appropriate indexes if table has any (other than Id in this case).

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Jony

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried directly joining Table1's i.id to the other table i.id's?  You are doing something different.  You join Table1.id to table2.id.  Then Table2.id to Table3.id.  Then Table3.id to Table4.id.  Try joining directly to table 1:

```
SELECT 
  i.id, i.hdm_id, i.tos,
  c.itemid, c.cid, 
  pr.code,
  p.lag

  FROM Table1 i
  JOIN Table2 c ON
  i.id = c.id 

  JOIN Table3 pr ON
  i.id = pr.id

  JOIN Table4 p ON
  i.id = p.id ;
```